# GPS coordinates not being retrieved

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, location

HI i have been trying to run this code from an example in a book but all i get is is the null value being passed to the variable and so i only get the message as "Your Current Position is : no location found"

The manifest file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.snooze.android.geopositioning"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_INTERNET" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

The main.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myLocationText"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Lastly is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.snooze.android.geopositioning;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);     
  }

  public void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) 
  {
    String latLongString;
    TextView myLocationText;
    myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
    if (location != null) 
    {
      double lat = location.getLatitude();
      double lng = location.getLongitude();
      latLongString = "Lat:" + String.valueOf(lat) + "\nLong:" + String.valueOf(lng);
    } 
    else
    {
      latLongString = "No location found";
     }
   myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" + latLongString);
  }
}
```

This is my first project so i am unfamiliar with a few of the workings but i copied everything as the book said but it does not work. Have tried various things on many sites, as well as answers from this forum....but to no avail.
I am using Eclipse and have added tried to run it on and AVD with Android 2.2 as well as for Google APIs.

What i think is that the co-ordinates are not being passed to the variables.
I had posted as a new user but was not able to comment on it so i have asked it again.
Lukas Kunth, chaitanya and wareninja thanks for your answers.
Apologies for the duplication.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the LocationListener without which your application cannot receive location updates.

```
Here is an excellent blog on GPS Location fetching..
```

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/

Comment: YEAHH!!! Thanks a lot Umesh its working now!!! I had used the locationlistener but had the order all wrong.